# How many days for the validation process on Google Play and Apple Store?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

I have been for many years a Symbian developer. Nokia says the validation process takes between 2 and 5 days, but in my experience after I send my application for being published it takes at least 10 days. If the application has problems, or if it does not meet some policies, I have to modify it and then to send again, and wait again for 10 days.

Then, my question is, how long is the validation process for apps published on Google Play and on Apple Store? I read somewhere else that Google has not a validation process and that the app appears on the store within 24 hours. I can not verify this statement. Can someone clarify this aspect and (possibly) report some link to Google and Apple developers' sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes usually 2 hours for the automated process to take place on the Play Store.

Might change in the future depending on server capacity and Google, but you can count on a 2 hours period before seing the app published

On the Apple side, as the process is human, a few days.

Comment: Last year, it took about 2 minutes for Google Play. Are you sure it's not just the keyword search indexing that's taking this long? If you use the package name to find it, it should appear much faster.

Comment: You are right, last year was way faster. As I have numerous devices at home and often check the update, I am sure that's 2 hours. I also tried to look for new app by url and in the Store without succes in that timeframe

Answer (score 1):

On apple, the average review time is 2 days, currently.  You can find out the latest averages on [this great site](http://appreviewtimes.com)

Comment: Updated to new URL for apple averages.